# What makes `git reset --hard` not getting me back to the last commit?

Tags: git, git-reset

Starting from commit A, I did some changes on the files. Before a mass renaming*, I did commit B. After that I wanted to redo it again so I did `git reset --hard`. I expected it to be exactly what I got when I just committed B. The folders with old name are retrieved with their files, which is expected. But:

- The files aren't changed like when I did B
- All folders with new name I created when mass renaming aren't deleted. They are all empty

`git log` shows that the HEAD is on commit B. Do you know what happens?

*The PowerShell command I use is:

```
ls -recurse | Where-Object {$_.name -match '[\d.*]'} | Rename-Item -newnam { $_.Name -replace '\d(.*)', '4$1' }
```

Comment: Git knows nothing of folders. If a change of commit happens to result in all files in a folder being deleted, that does not necessarily delete the folder.

Comment: `git reset --hard` has no effect on files that were not present in the previous commit. If you rename a file, you have effectively created a new file, and that file is not tracked. So if you `git reset --hard` now, that new file will remain.

Comment: I see. Why does it know nothing about folders? And would renaming folders equal with deleting all files in there and creating new ones? Is there a way to always track new files?

Comment: I don't know what "why" means in that question. That's just what Git is. And yes, if you rename a folder you have renamed all the files within it, because a file's "name" is its pathname including the folder it's in. And a rename, I remind you, is simply the deletion of one file and the creation of another; there is no built-in stored concept of "this is the same file but with a different name".

Comment: By the way, if you combine `git reset --hard` with some form of `git clean` you can end up a lot closer to having the working tree look exactly the way it did before, if that's important to you.

Comment: `-fd`, specifically, in case matt doesn't write up an answer. And optionally `-i` if you want Git to walk you through what it's doing, or `-n` for a dry-run.